# Messagebox with Django

Tags: django, messagebox

I have to make bills in my Django Project.
Before I create this bills, I have to ask the user, which kind of Bill, he want's to create. 
Therefore something like a Messagebox should be opened.
Is something like this possible in Django?

Thank's for your help!

Comment: Django is Python. You are free to program in django whatever you want to.

Comment: Yes, although the messagebox would be displayed with HTML/CSS/JS, it's not really a Django thing.

Comment: Sure, django is serverside, and I agree this looks like JS could be needed on the clientside. Still you need the corresponding view in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messageboxes are a part of the frontend, and not the backend where django mostly operates.

What you want is javascript and html, a popup messagebox is called a "Modal" and there are several implementations you can use. for example, [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) seems to be popular